# Click doesnt work on new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble with "$(".edit").on('click', function(){$(this).parent().toggleClass('editMode');" - it doesnt work on new elements...

```js
$('#addButton').click(function(){
$("#incomplete-tasks").append('<li><input type="checkbox"><label>' + $('#new-task').val() + '</label><input type="text"><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>')
});

$(".edit").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('editMode');
});
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="new-task">Add Item</label>
  <input id="new-task" type="text">
  <button id="addButton">Add</button>
</p>

<h3>Todo</h3>
<ul id="incomplete-tasks">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>Pay Bills</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </li>
```

Comment: check jQuery delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need event delegation.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("#incomplete-tasks").on("click", ".edit", function() { ... });
```

There is a good example here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/13411/).

editMode class is adding dynamically upon edit button click on li tag.

Code:

Html:

```
<p>
    <label for="new-task">Add Item</label>
    <input id="new-task" type="text" />
    <button id="addButton">Add</button>
</p>

<h3>Todo</h3>

<ul id="incomplete-tasks">
    <li id='dfdf'>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>Pay Bills</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addButton').on('click', function () {
        $("#incomplete-tasks").append('<li><input type="checkbox"/><label>' + $('#new-task').val() + '</label><input type="text"/><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>')
    });

    $("#incomplete-tasks").on("click", ".edit", function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('editMode');
    });
});
```